# SQL Not Exists and subquery

Tags: sql

I have these 2 tables:

- `Person` (`id, name, address, age`)
- `Knows` (`personA_id, personB_id`)

and I want to to return the names of `Person`'s that are more than 5 years older than the `Person`'s they know.

I am trying this:

```
SELECT 
    P1.name
FROM 
    Persons P1, Persons P2, Knows K1
WHERE 
    P1.id = K1.personA_id
    AND P2.id = K1.personB_id
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                    FROM Persons P3, Persons P4, Knows K2
                    WHERE P3.id = K2.personA_id
                      AND P4.id = K2.personB_id 
                      AND (P3.age - P4.age) <= 5)
```

But it's not working and I'm also not very sure why. Can you point me to right direction? Thanks in advance

Comment: How is it not working? What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: then why do you mean with "it's not working"?

Comment: I mean it's not returning what is supposed to. Does the query look correct for what i want to return?

Comment: What does it return, and what are you expecting it to return? **Help us help you.**

Comment: I'm sorry. It returns nothing. When i can see on the table that there are at least 2 results.

Comment: 5 years older than **all** the persons they know?

Comment: You should (have) put that in the question. My (excellent!) answer solves the case where at *least one* of the known persons is more than 5 years younger. ... back to the old drawing board ...

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really insist on the exists, this could do the trick:

```
SELECT p1.name AS the_older
     , p2.name AS the_younger
FROM Persons p1, Persons p2
WHERE p1.age - p2.age > 5 -- They are more than 5 years older
AND EXISTS (              -- than the one they know
    SELECT * 
    FROM Knows Kx
    WHERE Kx.personA_id = p1.id AND Kx.personB_id = p2.id
    );
```

Something similar can be done using the `JOIN` syntax (the age condition could also be moved into the join condition) :

```
SELECT p1.name AS the_older
     , p2.name AS the_younger
FROM Persons p1 
JOIN Persons p2 ON EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Knows Kx
    WHERE Kx.personA_id = p1.id AND Kx.personB_id = p2.id
    )
WHERE p1.age - p2.age > 5
;
```

---

UPDATE: After clarification of the question:

- personA must have some friends
- all of them more than 5 years younger

---

```
SELECT p1.name
FROM Persons p1
WHERE EXISTS ( -- must have friends
    SELECT * FROM Knows Kx
    WHERE Kx.personA_id = p1.id
    )
AND NOT EXISTS ( -- but no friends less than 5 years younger
    SELECT *
    FROM Knows Knx
    JOIN Persons p2 ON Knx.personB_id = p2.id
    WHERE Knx.personA_id = p1.id
    AND p1.age - p2.age <= 5
        );
    );
```

Comment: Even though i sort of get your query, i still don't completely understand why mine is not working

Comment: See the bullet list. (I think your original query misses the first bullet.)

Comment: `p1.age - p2.age` may be `-10` and this will be correct result! But this query will exclude it.

Comment: No, it is Ok; you can rewrite `AND p1.age - p2.age <= 5` to `p2.age >= p1.age -5` ; and it should **not** exist.

Answer (score 2):

For each person, find their age and the age of everyone they know.  Then calculate the maximum age of the people they know and filter this out:

```
SELECT P1.name
FROM Persons P1 JOIN
     Knows K1
     ON P1.id = K1.personA_id JOIN
     Persons P2 
     ON P2.id = K1.personB_id
GROUP BY P1.name, P1.age
HAVING ( p1.age - MAX(p2.age) ) > 5;
```

Although you can do this using `exists`, I think aggregation is a simpler query and simpler logic.

Comment: Well, i did use JOIN for another query that i too couldn't get it to work with EXISTS, but i'm afraid i have to make this one with NOT EXISTS. Any help on that? I mean. Do you see why my query is wrong?

Comment: @GeeKat88 why do you 'need' to use ´NOT EXISTS´?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to show relationship where the age difference is >5

```
SELECT P1.name
FROM Persons P1
INNER JOIN  Knows K1 ON P1.id = K1.personA_id
INNER JOIN  Persons P2 ON P2.id = K1.personB_id
WHERE  (P1.age - P2.age)  > 5
```

if you need to only get people that ALL their relationships have at least 5 years age difference then  @Gordon Linoff  answer is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

Starting point is union of Knows table:

```
SELECT    personA_id ,
          personB_id
FROM      @k k
UNION
SELECT    personB_id ,
          personA_id 
FROM      @k k
```

Because you will get incorrect result if you just verify from one side of table Knows.

```
DECLARE @p TABLE
    (
      id INT ,
      name NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      age INT
    )
DECLARE @k TABLE
    (
      personA_id INT ,
      personB_id INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @p
VALUES  ( 1, 'a', 10 ),
        ( 2, 'b', 14 ),
        ( 3, 'c', 30 ),
        ( 6, 'f', 35 ),
        ( 7, 'g', 45 )


INSERT  INTO @k
VALUES  ( 1, 2 ),
        ( 1, 3 ),
        ( 2, 3 ),
        ( 7, 6 )


SELECT  t.personA_id ,
        t.name
FROM    ( SELECT    personA_id ,
                    name ,
                    paage - pbage AS diff
          FROM      ( SELECT    personA_id ,
                                personB_id ,
                                pa.age paage ,
                                pb.age pbage ,
                                pa.name
                      FROM      @k k
                                JOIN @p pa ON pa.id = k.personA_id
                                JOIN @p pb ON pb.id = k.personB_id
                      UNION
                      SELECT    personB_id ,
                                personA_id ,
                                pb.age pbage ,
                                pa.age paage ,
                                pb.name
                      FROM      @k k
                                JOIN @p pa ON pa.id = k.personA_id
                                JOIN @p pb ON pb.id = k.personB_id
                    ) k
        ) t
GROUP BY t.personA_id ,
        t.name
HAVING  ( MIN(diff) > 5 )
```

Output:

```
personA_id  name
3           c
7           g
```

If you will join directly on table Knows then you will get:

```
SELECT  t.personA_id ,
        t.name
FROM    ( SELECT    personA_id ,
                    name ,
                    paage - pbage AS diff
          FROM      ( SELECT    personA_id ,
                                personB_id ,
                                pa.age paage ,
                                pb.age pbage ,
                                pa.name
                      FROM      @k k
                                JOIN @p pa ON pa.id = k.personA_id
                                JOIN @p pb ON pb.id = k.personB_id
                    ) k
        ) t
GROUP BY t.personA_id ,
        t.name
HAVING  ( MIN(diff) > 5 )
```

Output:

```
personA_id  name
7           g
```